# Text pre-processing How to run many scripts at once

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have many scripts for text cleaning, is there a way to execute all of them at once instead of doing that one by one, for example I have :

```
sed -i -r "s/[’'–]/ /g" *.txt

sed -i 's/Aβ/ ABeta /g' ./*.txt
```

I have about 10 of them, how can I run all of them at once?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `-e` to specify multiple commands to run:

```
 sed -i -r -e 's/[’'–]/ /g' -e 's/Aβ/ ABeta /g' *.txt
```

Generally:

```
sed [-flags] -e 'command1' -e 'command2' .... -e 'last command' inputfile
```

Comment: You can also join them with `;`, no?